# Efficient pandas transformation of timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that is 23 columns and 4,044 rows and looks like the below:

```
+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| _id | _ts | metric1 | metric2 | metric3 | etc... |
+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|   1 | 300 |     .01 |      10 |       1 |        |
|   1 | 600 |     .02 |      25 |       1 |        |
|   1 | 900 |     .07 |      47 |       1 |        |
+-----+-----+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I would like to pivot the data in such a way that I can combine `_ts` + `metric` to make a column for regression model purposes, e.g. `300_metric1`, `600_metric1`, etc.

Right now if I put the dataframe through this function:

```
def build_timeseries_features(df):
    df['_ts'] = df['_ts'].astype(str)
    df = df.set_index('_ts', append=True).stack().unstack(0).T
    df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
    concat = pd.concat([df.iloc[[x]].dropna(1).reset_index(drop=True) for x in range(1, 26)], axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([concat, df.iloc[[4032]].dropna(1).reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)  # gets the 14th day data by index

    return df
```

I get the following back, which is exactly how I want it:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| _id | 300_metric1 | 600_metric1 | 900_metric1 | etc... |
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|   1 |         .01 |         .02 |         .07 |        |
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

The issue with this is that it is *extremely* slow (time profiling shows this taking 43.8 seconds) and I need to be able to do this on a dataset that is ~10,000 ids, so ~40million rows....so this will take about 5 days to finish

Any thoughts on how I can speed this up?

Comment: So you then want ~40 million columns? Reconsider this approach. Panel/time series regression modeling requires long format as you originally have it.

Comment: @Parfait could you point me to an example of doing a regression in long format?

Comment: @Parfait also this will not generate 40 million rows, each of the 10,000 ids would have the same column names and would be concatenated

Comment: How many `_ts` distinct values? This will determine the number of columns.

Comment: @Parfait in the dataset there 4044 distinct _ts values, but i only want columns for the first 24 and the last _ts values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to transform data frame from long to wide format. However, one nuance to your needs is selecting the top 24 distinct values and last value which you can do with `series` manipulation. Below takes first two values, changing according to your needs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id': list(range(1,11))*5,
                   '_ts':[300 for i in range(10)] + [600 for i in range(10)] +
                         [900 for i in range(10)] + [1200 for i in range(10)] +
                         [1500 for i in range(10)],
                   'metric1': np.random.randn(50),
                   'metric2': np.random.randn(50),
                   'metric3': np.random.randn(50)})

# FIRST 2 AND LAST VALUES (SORTED IN _ts ORDER)
first2vals = pd.Series(df['_ts'].unique()).sort_values().tolist()[:2]
lastval = pd.Series(df['_ts'].unique()).sort_values().tolist()[-1]

# FILTER DATA FRAME BY ABOVE LISTS
df = df[df['_ts'].isin(first2vals + [lastval])]

# PIVOT DATA FRAME
pvtdf = df.pivot_table(index="_id", columns=['_ts'], 
                       values=['metric1', 'metric2', 'metric3']).reset_index()

# EXTRACT NEW COLUMNS FROM HIERARCHICAL INDEX
newcols = [str(i[1])+'_'+str(i[0]) for i in pvtdf.columns[1:].values]
pvtdf.columns = pvtdf.columns.get_level_values(0)
pvtdf.columns = ['id'] + newcols
```

**Output**

```
print(pvtdf.head())

#    id  300_metric1  600_metric1  1500_metric1  300_metric2  600_metric2  1500_metric2  300_metric3  600_metric3  1500_metric3
# 0   1    -1.158317     1.677042     -0.763932     0.673375    -1.345052     -0.754341    -0.023793    -1.212369      1.566882
# 1   2     1.699644     0.700463      1.351290    -0.672567    -0.941611      0.739071     1.270882     0.079738     -1.272970
# 2   3     0.414411    -1.110571      0.744850    -0.822367     1.897526     -0.344387    -0.382097     0.631639      0.515618
# 3   4     0.744617     0.708938     -0.851571    -1.312690     1.817234     -1.084037    -1.253749    -1.554973     -0.162376
# 4   5     1.233120     0.569504      0.560808     0.437648     0.293689      0.675582     1.396155     0.210394     -0.504569
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a hacky way on my own. This runs in ~20ms

```
def time_series_columns(df):
    data_values = []
    for x in df.columns:
        data_values.append(df[x].values.tolist())

    columns = []

    for metric in df.columns.values:
        for ts in np.arange(0, 7500, 300):
            columns.append("{}_{}".format(ts, metric))

    data = [[item for sublist in [listy[:25] for listy in data_values] for item in sublist]]
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

    return new_df
```